# For loop taking 30+ minutes to run

Tags: excel, vba

I can't figure out what is making the sub below run so slowly. All other parts of the puzzle run very quickly and don't have issues. The code below goes through a list of insurance polices contained on a Worksheet in the Workbook containing the code, groups them by account #, and then writes them to an external workbook that has been opened by a previous sub. It works, but I have to be doing inefficient with the code. SourceWorksheet has a little less than 4,000 rows and DestWorksheet ends up with about 1,300 rows.

So far, I've set calculations to manual and turned off AutoSave, screen updating, events and alerts (done in the Main sub that calls this one). I've also declared variables for the worksheet names rather than refer to them by their full Workbook/Worksheet names and cleared the clipboard whenever I've used it prior to the code below. The logjam is in the For loop.  Please feel free to make fun of me and/or my programming practices in your reply.  Any assistance is very much appreciated.  Hopefully, I didn't break too many forum rules in my first effort.

```
Sub Build_Account_List()
Application.StatusBar = "Building the account list"
Dim FindTotal As Integer
Dim AccountPremium As Long
Dim OppRowNum As Long 'Counts the number of rows on the Raw Data tab
Dim AccountNumber As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim LOB As String
Dim WCFlag As String
Dim UmbFlag As String
Dim PkgFlag As String
Dim AutoFlag As String
Dim IMFlag As String
Dim OppListRow As Long 'Determines the row number being written on DestWorksheet
Dim AccountName As String
Set SourceWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data")
Set DestWorksheet = Workbooks("Team Custom Opportunities.xlsx").Worksheets("Custom Opportunities")
OppRowNum = 2 'Row number to start with for the SourceWorksheet
OppListRow = 5 'Row number to start with for the DestWorksheet
    Do While FindTotal = 0 'Figure out how many rows of data there are on the Source Worksheet
        ThisWorkbook.Activate
        With Worksheets("Raw Data")
            If .Cells(OppRowNum, 1) = "Total" Then
                FindTotal = 1
            Else
                OppRowNum = OppRowNum + 1
            End If
        End With
    Loop
    OppRowNum = OppRowNum - 1
    With SourceWorksheet.Range("A1:J" & OppRowNum)
        .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns("B"), Order1:=xlDescending, Key2:=.Columns("C"), Order2:=xlAscending, Key3:=.Columns("D"), Order3:=xlAscending, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
    End With
    For i = 2 To OppRowNum 'Identify accounts from list of LOBs, total the premium, and write data to DestWorksheet
        With SourceWorksheet
        LOB = .Cells(i, 7)
        Select Case LOB
            Case "Workers Comp"
                WCFlag = "WC "
            Case "Business Auto"
                AutoFlag = "Auto "
            Case "Inland Marine"
                IMFlag = "IM "
            Case "Supported Umbrella"
                UmbFlag = "Umb"
            Case "SL Unsupported Umbrella - Excess Capacity"
                UmbFlag = "Umb"
            Case "SL Unsupported Umbrella - Primary"
                UmbFlag = "Umb"
            Case Else
                PkgFlag = "Pkg "
        End Select
        AccountPremium = AccountPremium + .Cells(i, 5)
        If IsNumeric(Mid(.Cells(i, 10), 3, 1)) = True Then
            AccountNumber = Left(.Cells(i, 10), 8)
        Else
            AccountNumber = Mid(.Cells(i, 10), 12, 8)
        End If
        If AccountNumber <> Mid(.Cells((i + 1), 10), 12, 8) Then
            OppListRow = OppListRow + 1
            AccountName = SourceWorksheet.Cells(i, 3)
            DestWorksheet.Cells(OppListRow, 2) = SourceWorksheet.Cells(i, 2)
            DestWorksheet.Cells(OppListRow, 3) = SourceWorksheet.Cells(i, 3)
            DestWorksheet.Hyperlinks.Add DestWorksheet.Cells(OppListRow, 4), Address:="https://xxxxxxx.com/gw/account-details/" & AccountNumber, TextToDisplay:="" & AccountNumber
            DestWorksheet.Cells(OppListRow, 5) = SourceWorksheet.Cells(i, 4)
            DestWorksheet.Cells(OppListRow, 6) = " "
            DestWorksheet.Cells(OppListRow, 9) = AccountPremium
            DestWorksheet.Cells(OppListRow, 10) = Left(SourceWorksheet.Cells(i, 6), 12)
            DestWorksheet.Cells(OppListRow, 12) = PkgFlag & IMFlag & AutoFlag & WCFlag & UmbFlag
            DestWorksheet.Cells(OppListRow, 13) = SourceWorksheet.Cells(i, 8)
            DestWorksheet.Cells(OppListRow, 14) = SourceWorksheet.Cells(i, 9)
            WCFlag = ""
            AutoFlag = ""
            IMFlag = ""
            UmbFlag = ""
            PkgFlag = ""
            AccountPremium = 0
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
        End With
    Next
            DestWorksheet.Cells(2, 2) = "Submissions updated"
            DestWorksheet.Cells(3, 2) = Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY hh mm AMPM")
    DestWorksheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need a `Do...Loop` to find the word `Total`. You can use `Range.Find` or `Application.Match` for that.

Comment: Bulk load variant arrays and loop them instead of the cells on a worksheet.  Every time the code pierces the veil between vba and the worksheet it slows down to do that action.  If you work with data in memory it will be quick.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen - I made that change.

Comment: @Scott, I'm going to build that out. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Create an array to store the results and paste to your worksheet when the loop has finished

Comment: Thanks, everyone!  The array did the trick.  I'm down to 1 minute to run this sub.